# Batch file to merge specific files into one?

Tags: batch-file

I am newbie with windows batch command so please spare me for any irrelevant help.
Basically i want to merge certain files using type command of windows but since those files are coming from various sources i need to search in file name for source filter and only merge those files. i have tried writing below code but it's not doing the job for me.

```
@echo off
set filter=%1
set final_file=%2
echo %filter%
echo %final_file%
for %f in (*.dlt) do(
    echo %f
    if find %filter "%f ( 
        do type "%f" >> %final_file
    )
)
```

Comment: each `%f`in your `for` statement must be `%%f`. You need to double the `%` on the `metavariable` if running from a batch file. Sadly, your problem description, "it's not doing the job for me" doesn't give us many clues about why the process isn't doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: @Mangoo How would you resolve above problem? Just simply thinking for it that you have to loop thru all files with extension .dlt and file name must contain filter 'Engine' for ex : Filexxx_Engine_27_07_2017_01.dlt and then merging all such files using type command into Engine_All.dlt ?

Comment: You want to merge only `*.dlt` files ? and your master folder is located where ?

Comment: thanks for answer, i will be passing my master folder as parameter but instead of merging all .dlt files i want to search for some string like Engine in individual dlt files and then only merge those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that i made to merge all `*.bat` files in one file; so you can easily modify it to your needs :
Just you need to modify the variable `Set "Filter_Ext=dlt"` and the `Set "MasterFolder=%userprofile%\desktop"` to yours

```bat
@echo off
Mode 75,3 & Color 9E
Title Merge all *.bat in one file
Set "MasterFolder=%userprofile%\desktop"
Set "OutPut=Output_Merged_Files.txt"
Set "Filter_Ext=bat"
If exist "%OutPut%" Del "%OutPut%"
echo(
echo           Please Wait a while we generate the output file ...
@For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /s /b /A-D "%MasterFolder%\*.%Filter_Ext%"') Do (
cls
echo(
echo          Please Wait a While ...   Merging "%%~nxa" ...
    (
        echo ====================================================
        echo  Contents of "%%a"
        echo ====================================================
        Type "%%a"
        echo(
    )>> "%OutPut%"
)
Start "" "%OutPut%"
```

***Edit Merge all .dlt in one file***

```bat
@echo off
Mode 75,3 & Color 9E
Title Merge all *.dlt in one file
Set "MasterFolder=%~1"
Set "OutPut=Output_Merged_Files.txt"
Set "Filter_Ext=dlt"
Set "KeyWord=Engine"
If exist "%OutPut%" Del "%OutPut%"
echo(
echo           Please Wait a while we generate the output file ...
@For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /s /b /A-D "%MasterFolder%\*.%Filter_Ext%" ^|find /I "%KeyWord%"') Do (
cls
echo(
echo          Please Wait a While ...   Merging "%%~nxa" ...
    (
        echo ====================================================
        echo  Contents of "%%a"
        echo ====================================================
        Type "%%a"
        echo(
    )>> "%OutPut%"
)
Start "" "%OutPut%"
```

Comment: This is perfect but i only need two small modifications, 1. Out of all dlt files i want to only merge dlt files which has for ex Engine string in file name and 2. I will be calling this file from python so i need to pass these data as parameter.